# How to combine .htaccess rules

Tags: .htaccess

I have a problem on share hosting to combine `.htaccess` rules to say:

- path of the `index.php` (in subdirectory)
- redirect www to without www

The share host have a directory public_html and my `index.php` is on public_html/web
I have added on `.htaccess` at the root:

```bash
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !web/ RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1 [l]
```

It well works, but how to add the information of www redirect to without www?

```bash
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

We have tested many syntax like below but it redirect `https://www.example.com` redirect to `https://example.com/web` and URL is bad in my CMS. We test redirect directory /web before or after and it is same.

```bash
RewriteEngine On
#Redirect from www to without -www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
#Redirect to directory /web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/

RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1 [L]
```

I have tried many syntax with the hoster but I can't find the solution

```bash
RewriteEngine on
#Redirect to subdirectory /web
  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ NC
  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/$1 L 
#Redirection from www to without www
  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ NC 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1  R=301,L
```

Comment: The HTTP -> HTTPS redirect _needs_ to happen first. You used status code 301 already, so your browser might have cached a faulty redirect - clear your cache, or test in a private window. And change that to 302 for as long as you are still testing.